# Why are hook_form_alter updates being reverted?

Tags: forms

After I clear all caches I can see my update is effective in the *Create Article* form. Great.

But as soon as I refresh the page, or come to it afresh to create another Article, the unmodified value of `#file_upload_title` re-appears.

This is what I added to `template.php`:

```
function seven_form_article_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['field_photo_gallery']['und']['#file_upload_title'] = 'Add a new file or multiiple files';
}
```

Comment: try clearing your browser cache, or try it on a different browser to see if the problem persists

Comment: your using seven  as theme ? otherwise adapt the hook to  YOUR_THEME_NAME_form_article_node_form_alter

Comment: Hmmm. Thanks for trying to help. But "... I can see my update is effective ..." so clearly the function is named correctly even though I might have chosen `hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()` instead of `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` - I will investigate further. As stated, all works as expected immediately Drupal  caches are cleared (NB not using APC server side cache either); but, yes, both Mozilla (Firefox) and Webkit (Safari and Chrome) browsers behave the same even after client side browser cache emptied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `seven_form_article_node_form_alter`was correctly named but not placed in the correct file in the correct folder.

The function `seven_form_article_node_form_alter` has to go in `template.php` in a (sub)theme of the administration theme `seven` - of course - and not in the  `template.php` of my "front-end" theme.

The fact that I had a function in there with a prefix other than my from-end theme's should have signalled my mistake.

What mislead me was a quirk of Drupal cache clear. It happens that  clearing the Drupal cache actually (and incorrectly) caused my form alterations to be displayed as my function must have been the last one in the chain to have taken effect. It was only after a subsequent page build / refresh that the form alter's effects (correctly) disappeared.  So this is a quirk of Drupal cache clear that needs to be taken account of in this edge case.

Consequently I have created an administration sub theme into whose `template.php` file the function now sits (Does it count as one line of code or two? ;-). All is now working as it should.